# koalas: does it have PARTITION BY + ROW_COUNT()?

Tags: sql, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I'm trying to use Koalas to process my dataframes.

Does it have rolling window functions over partitions? Something like `PARTITION BY` and `ROW_NUMBER()` in Hive or Postgres?